# I am using GitHub to host my website. Which is the most suitable Disqus platform to be used?

Tags: github, disqus

I am using GitHub to host my website. Which is the most suitable Disqus platform to be used to enable commenting system on my Website?

By Platform I mean :

WordPress
Universal Code
Joomla
Blogger 
Tumblr
Squarespace etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "most suitable disqus"? There is only one Disqus, as far as I recall. Suitable how?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GitHub Pages, you can't use *any* of those Web platforms you mentioned, because they all either presume you have your own hosting space or are hosted on their own infrastructure.  If you want to use Tumblr, sign up for it.  If you want to use Joomla, get a virtual private server.

GitHub Pages constrains you to Jekyll, plus a finite set of plugins.  Which may be fine, if that's all you need.  If your website doesn't need any sort of custom backend logic (e.g. a database), you can use GitHub Pages just fine.  Disqus can be added to your site with [just a little bit of JavaScript](https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/).

The reasons you'd want to use GitHub pages are worthy of a separate question, but in a nutshell you get a free static website.